# About Nginx $arg_name syntax

Tags: nginx-location

Please tell me the syntax to start with with $arg_name in Nginx

For example, I want to write if $arg_name starts with Test.
I want to write a syntax that matches the following

```
http://localhost/sss?name=Test1
http://localhost/sss?name=Test2

location /
{
　if($arg_name=="Test")　→I want to write the syntax starting with Test here
  {
    return 500;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can use regexes

This is completely untested. But maybe it will get you closer.

Using the suggestion here to use location instead of an if.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-rule-for-wildcard-url

```
location ~ /.*name=Test.*/ {
    ...
}
```

Here's my favorite regex playground if you don't already have one.
https://regex101.com/r/Q89zXg/2/

Comment: Thank you for answering　It was very helpful.　I'm going to test

Comment: After testing above, it didn't seem to match.
In addition to the above, the following settings are made. Is this the cause of the mismatch?
location / {
.........
}